# A Distributed Cost-Distance Algorithm

Tags: raster, algorithm, parallel-processing, geotrellis

I'm currently trying to implement a distributed cost-distance algorithm, however I can't seem to invent my own and still make it fast. I've been googling around a bit but haven't found anything that would allow me to compute the cost-distance for a tiled raster in a "map-reduce" manner, e.g. that would run efficiently on Apache Spark. Does anybody have any good papers or reference implementations of this?

I'm working on GeoTrellis (https://github.com/geotrellis/geotrellis) In Scala, we have are using our own raster-processing library. I'm looking for papers essentially in this question.

Comment: What raster-processing API are you using (e.g. GDAL, ArcPy etc) or have you written your own for that too?  KNowing your API and coding language will help direct the answers.

Comment: @MappaGnosis, Sorry, I'll edit the question.